# Should I create separate contract copy for every post or just one contract to deal with all posts?

Tags: contract-development

My Ethereum app consists of creating a post like on Facebook and people can like/comment on it. Should I create separate contract copy for every post or just one contract to deal with all posts?

Answer (score 1):

You should store them all in one contract; there's no reason to create an arbitrary amount of contracts.

In Solidity, you can use a dynamically sized array to store all the posts. A simple example would be a contract like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Facebook
{
    struct Post
    {
        address sender;
        string text;
    }
    Post[] public posts;
    function createPost(string text) public
    {
        posts.push(Post(msg.sender, text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this. But I really want to know when do we create new contract for different things? In which case do we do that?

Comment: @SHIVAMSETHI, Once a contract has been deployed on the blockchain, you can't change its source code. If you want to change it, you will have to deploy a new contract with different source code.